# Flex Builder 4, ZendAMF and Data Services - Error?

Tags: php, apache-flex, eclipse, zend-framework, wamp

I'm trying to set up my Flex Builder 4 dev environment, up to and including PHP and the ZendFramework on a WAMP stack on my hard drive.

Everything goes swimmingly until I try to set up a data service. I point it to the php class file, it populates the various fields in the form so I know it understood it, and I press next. After a little bit of tweaking I have the ZendFramework installed and everything seems to be pointing the right way, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

"Make sure that Zend Framework is installed correctly and the parameter "amf.production" is not set to true in the amf_config.ini file located in the project output folder. 
Warning: include_once(C:\wamp\www\TestDrive-debug\EmployeeService.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 146"

What could be causing a permissions error like that? It's not on the system level because I went into properties and fully opened that file up so even a basic user has full permissions - still no dice.

I'm not reeeally a PHP guy so this is a bit beyond my skillset. Has anyone encountered this problem before? I'm just following the tutorial I have here and it SHOULD work. I'm just not clear on what would be causing a permissions issue like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you find any solution to this , please tell me if you have.

Comment: Oh man, this is from almost a year ago - I'm sorry, I probably resolved this problem and moved on without even realizing. There is one answer below, let me know if that helps - if not, I'm going to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by changing the encoding of the php file. There must be some invisible characters in the file that were screwing up the parsing. Try saving the php service file with different encoding and see if it works for you. The one that worked for me was created by eclipse. I copy pasted the code in it, saved, and boom it worked!

Answer (score 1):

just had same issue and resolved same as OP, just resave file with notepad, funny deal, but it happens

Answer (score 0):

inside the folder of amf_Config.ini , create a new file amf_config2.ini , copy the contents of amf_config.ini as it is into amf_config2.ini , now inside amf_config2 double quote the value of parameter webroot (webroot="xxxxx") save ur amf_config2 , open gateway.php which would be also inside the same dir , change $configfile = "$dir/amf_config.ini" to 
$configfile = "$dir/amf_config2.ini" , save it and try